# step by step progress logging for oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql

I'm having a message_log table with ID, Severity Level, Message, Log Date & Time.

I'm using below procedure to insert log messages to log table in my PL/SQL scripts.

```
add_log(ID,'START','DEBUG','No CDR Detail to be processed', sysdate);
```

But in case of failure I see some message are not getting logged. What is the best method to log step by step progress of a plsql progress (until failure point if needed)?

```
create or replace procedure add_log 
        (stp varchar2, code varchar2, log_message varchar2, logdat date)
    is 

begin

    insert into message_log 
    (SEQ,PROC_STEP,
    CODE,
    LOG_MESSAGE,
    LOG_DATE
    )
    values 
    (log_SEQ.NEXTVAL,stp,code,log_message,logdat)
    ;

end;
```

Comment: Use proper `exception handling` in your PLSQL scripts, and utilize it for inserting messages to the log.

Comment: Are you committing the transaction either in `add_log` procedure or after calling add_log in the PL/SQL block?

Answer (score 4):

> "in case of failure I don't see some message are getting logged. What is the best method to log step by step progress of a plsql progress (until failure point if needed)."

Your ADD_LOG() procedure doesn't include a `commit` - presumably you are relying on the wider transaction to persist log records. The snag is, if the broader transaction fails it rolls back and takes your log messages with it.

This is one of the few legitimate uses for the autonomous transaction pragma. This creates an isolated transaction (a nested session as it were) so we can commit without affecting the outer transaction.

```
create or replace procedure add_log (stp varchar2, code varchar2, log_message varchar2, logdat date)
is 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
    insert into message_log 
    (SEQ,PROC_STEP,
    CODE,
    LOG_MESSAGE,
    LOG_DATE
    )
    values 
    (log_SEQ.NEXTVAL,stp,code,log_message,logdat)
    ;
    COMMIT;  
end;
```

If you make this change to ADD_LOG() all your messages will be committed regardless of what happens to the calling transaction.